# Deleting from Android SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, onclick

***Question***

---

I am trying to use a button to delete the first entry to my database. I thought I had the code right but it does not seem to be deleting any of the data, when the delete button is pressed android is setup so which this as it `onClick` method:-

```
public void delete(View view)
 {
     datasource.open();
     datasource.deleteTitle(0);
     datasource.close();
 }
```

the delete method it is calling is this method here:-

```
 public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
            "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

is there a different way I should be doing this?

The button is set up like this :-

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete First" 
        android:onClick="delete"/>
```

I am using the built in `onClick` to go to the method I want. I am using this in other parts of the application and it works just fine.

***Solution:***

---

From the accepted answer, I took the code in that and created a call in the DatabaseHelper class names delete first. The code I used was :-

```
public void deleteFirst()
{
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null); 

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        long rowId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID)); 

        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID +  "=" + rowId, null);
   }
}
```

and I then changed the code  I gave above to:

```
public void delete(View view)
 {
     datasource.open();
     datasource.deleteFirst();
     fillData();
     datasource.close();
 }
```

with the `fillData()` method refreshing the view.

Comment: what's the LogCat error or is it runtime error?

Comment: there is not error its just not doing anything. the onClick for the delete button is what i have gave above. yet when i click it none of the statements seem to execute

Comment: have you attached the button using `findViewById(R.id.buttonId)`?

Comment: no i have not as i never needed to do it before. i have a menu set up in a similar manner which has the button pointing at a public void which then executes and opens the next screen

Comment: The delete code is fine... it must be in your onClickListener/onClick method.  Post the whole thing so we can get a look at that.

Comment: i added the button setup which is using the built in onClick android method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first record in the database will not always have an ID of "0". Each time you insert a new record the primary key will increment by 1. So what you need is to get the id of the first record, and perform the delete using that id.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null); 

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        long rowId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID)); 

        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID +  "=" + rowId, null);
   }
```

Comment: right thats makes sense. i thought i was missing something. where should i put them statments then?

Comment: just before the db.delete in your code I guess. I really can't tell since I have no idea how you implemented your database. But that's the idea, perform a query first to get the first record on the database and get its ID, then delete it using that ID.

Comment: what i did was i used your code as its own database call named "deleteFirst" that way i have specific code that will delete the first value of the database. 

should i edit my post to show how i have it set up now?

Answer (score 0):

stop worrieng about sql and use greenDAO :) very simple, super easy and lightweight sqllite framework for android

http://greendao-orm.com/

Comment: not sure i can change that so far into the development of the app. its my final project and i have stated that i will use SQLite as part of the bases for the project so changing it will change what i am setting out to do. though i will look into it and see if it makes things easier. if it can be implemented even at this late stage i will deffinatey switch to it