# Delete data from database and listview on button click in android

Tags: android-listview

I am trying to delete a record trough listview from database. I am somehow got suceed in removing the record from list but didn't find any help to delete it from database.
Below is the code of my adapter. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class Row_keyskill extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {


    private ArrayList<String> listName=new ArrayList<String>();
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;
    String id;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    int position,position1;

    public Row_keyskill(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listName) {
        super();
        this.listName = listName;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listName.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listName.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(context,"row item clicked"+listName.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      /*  int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        id = listName.get(position);
        // listName.remove(position);
        Log.e("Row_keyskill", "position id:  "+id);
        position1=position+1;
        Log.e("Row_keyskill", "position1 id:  "+position1);
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM USER_SKILLS WHERE U_SKILL_NAME ='" + id + "'");
       // itemDelete();*/
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {

        public TextView txtName;
        public ImageView btn_delete;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowdata_keyskill,null);

            view.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.keyskill_row);
           // view.btn_delete=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

           // view.btn_delete.setTag(position);


            convertView.setTag(view);
        }
        else
        {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        view.txtName.setText(listName.get(position));
        //view.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageView btn_delete=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        btn_delete.setTag(position);
        btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something

                int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
              //  SQLiteDatabase db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("JOB_PORTAL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                 id = listName.get(position);
               // listName.remove(position);
                Log.e("Row_keyskill", "position id:  " + id);
                position1=position+1;
                Log.e("Row_keyskill", "position1 id:  "+position1);
                listName.remove(position);
               itemDelete(id);
               //
                 //id = listName.get(position);
                //  db.execSQL("DELETE * FROM USER_SKILLS WHERE U_SKILL_NAME ='" + position + "'");
                 // db.delete("USER_SKILLS", new String("U_SKILL_NAME=?"), new String[]{id});
                  //or some other task*/

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }



}


private void itemDelete(String id) {
        //db = null;
        try {
//              db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("JOB_PORTAL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
          // db.delete("USER_SKILLS", new String("U_SKILL_ID=?"), new String[]{id});
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM USER_SKILLS WHERE U_SKILL_NAME ='" + id + "'");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Database error: " + se, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997553)

Comment: Thanks for replying but it didn't helped as i am getting null pointer exception where i create cursor.